# Angular 6 how to get count of the particular column based on same value from an array of object

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have an array of object and also I am using foreach loop in typescript.Here as per my array it contains 2 columns having value progress:100 and others are less that 100.So here I need to calculate the count of columns having progress:100,for ex here it should be 2.Also I need to get the count of all columns having progress value is less or not 100.for ex here 2.Then I need to append into div.I have tried but its adding not counting.Here is the code below

### app.component.html

```
<div>Progress : 2{{count}}</div><div>completed : 2{{count}}</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
declare var require: any;
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit{

      arrayVal:any;
      currentVal : any;
  title = 'projectchart';
  public array = [{"id":1,"progress":100},{"id":3,"progress":70},{"id":5,"progress":50},{"id":6,"progress":100}];
  ngOnInit(){
     let count=0;
     this.array.forEach((item, index) => {
     console.log(item.progress) ;
     count +=item.progress ;
});
     console.log(count);
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, You are adding the progress value in count. Please try this..

```
ngOnInit(){
   let progress_count=0;
   let completed_count=0;
   this.array.forEach((item, index) => {
   if (item.progress == 100) {
    progress_count++;
   } else {
    completed_count++;
   }
});
   console.log('Progress count :',progress_count);
   console.log('Completed count :',completed_count);
}
```

And use progress_count and completed_count in your HTML

Answer (score 1):

Change this line

```
count +=item.progress;
```

To

```
if (item.progress === 100) {count += 1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
progressCount:number = 0;
completedCount:number = 0;


ngOnInit() {
this.array.forEach(item => {
  if (item.progress < 100) {
    this.progressCount ++;
  } else {
    this.completedCount ++;
  }
});
}
```

HTML:

```
<div>Progress : 2{{progressCount}}</div><div>completed : 2{{completedCount}}</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use library like [underscore](https://underscorejs.org/), where a function like countBy will do what you want.

In your case:

```
_.countBy(array, (item) => item.progress === 100 ? 'completed' : 'progress');
```

the result will be:

`{completed: 2, progress: 2}`